# How to INSERT data in for loop

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to insert multiple values into my table. One value will change in every query. I have INSERT like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (id, a) Values((select nextval('seq_myTable'), 'A' + index + '_x'
```

Where 'a' is string and 'index' should change in every loop.
I know i should do it inside some loop in postgressql.

Comment: have a look here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/plpgsql-control-structures.html under "40.6.3 Loops" you will find the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to go for Loops. You may simply use `generate_series`

```
knayak=# select nextval('seq_myTable'), 'A' || index || '_x' as s 
 FROM generate_series(1,10) as index;
 nextval | s
---------+----------
       1 | A1_x
       2 | A2_x
       3 | A3_x
       4 | A4_x
       5 | A5_x
       6 | A6_x
       7 | A7_x
       8 | A8_x
       9 | A9_x
      10 | A10_x
(10 rows)
```

**Insert statement**

```
INSERT INTO myTable (id, a) select nextval('seq_myTable') as id, 
 'A' || index || '_x' as a 
FROM generate_series(1,10) as index;
```